# Difficulty in evaluating $\lim_{t\to x}\frac{t^2f(x)-x^2f(t)}{t-x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

We have the differentiable function $f(x)$, on interval $(0,\infty)$ such that $f(1)=1$ and  $\lim_{t\to x}\frac{t^2f(x)-x^2f(t)}{t-x}=1\,\,\forall x>0$, so, we need to find $f(x)$. Applying L'Hopital's rule and substituting $t\rightarrow x$ quickly simplified the equation to:

$$2xf(x)-x^2f'(x)=1$$

Now, this equation is probably some type of differential equation, and further, I can't solve it and am stuck here. I haven't studied much of differential equations so far. Please help in solving this equation or suggest some other method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Comment: Paul's Online Notes is more useful: [Linear Differential Equations](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) with practice problems at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The equation can be written as $(\frac {f(x)} {x^{2}})'=-\frac 1 {x^{4}}$. Integrate both sides.

For the general method of solving such an equation see https://byjus.com/maths/integrating-factor/

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation to use the integrating factor method:

$$f'(x) + \left(-\frac{2}{x} \right) f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

where one possible integrating factor is $e^{- \int 2/x dx} = e^{-2 \ln |x|} = \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Then multiplying both sides by the integrating factor, $\frac{1}{x^2} f'(x) + -\frac{2}{x^3} f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^4}$ and the left-hand side can be rewritten using the product rule.